# WSO2 API Manager 2.0.0: How to disable anonymous access to API store?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

By default, user can access API store URL and can see published API without having to login. Is it possible to configure API Manager to force the user to always login first before they can see the published API.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict API visibility on the Store via the Publisher (https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Key+Concepts#KeyConcepts-APIvisibilityandsubscription) , so that only registered users can see published APIs.

Restricting access to the /store domain is a network/proxy matter.